# Facebook Registration Plugin Locale not working when using XFBML

Tags: facebook, registration

When I want to implement the Registration Plugin with XFBML (because I want to use validation for custom fields), the locale setting isn't working. It always takes en_US as its locale, no matter what I use.

```
<fb:registration redirect-uri="REDIRECT_URI"
locale='de_DE'
fields='JSON OF ALL THE FIELDS'
onvalidate="validate"></fb:registration>
```

When I use the iFrame implementation, the locale works, but not the validation part.
Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you post your js api loader here?

Answer (score 1):

When you select to use XFBML, you can set locale by calling js file of that language.

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#appId=appid&xfbml=1"></script>
```